# How control order in which annotation elements appear?

Tags: java, annotations

When creating new annotation

```
public @interface Invariant {
    String min();
    String max();
    String Default();
    String freeform();
}
```

Elements appear in what seems to be alphabetical order. I wonder if there is a way to force the same order as established in the annotation itself?

I get

```
    @Invariant(Default = "", freeform = "", max = "", min = "")
```

I'd like to get

```
    @Invariant(min = "", max = "", Default = "", freeform = "")
```

Comment: _Where_ do the elements appear in alphabetical order, exactly?

Comment: D before f before ma before mi. Thought this was clear.

Comment: No, that's not what I'm asking. I'm asking what place you saw the elements being listed in alphabetical order instead of the order you expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of the elements in an annotation is irrelevant, it makes no sense at all to force an ordering. Don't waste your efforts on this, it's not worth it - and anyway, you can't force an ordering, it's just not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No, I doubt if there is a way to force the order of the attributes.